# How can I call an keyword to an dictionary inside of a string in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to save some data from a dictionary in a terminal game I wrote, I've got the scores inside of a dictionary and I want to call those scores to write them on a note. I tried:

```
with open(path, 'w') as File:
File.write(f"player score is {str(score[\"Player\"])}\n"
           f"computer score is {str(score[\"computer\"])}")
```

but this does not seem to work.
How can I solve this problem without rewriting how I save scores?

Comment: Do you want to append it to the end of the file? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may just be that you need to use differing `"` / `'` when working with f-strings, or they'll think they've ended early.

```
with open(path, 'w') as File:
    File.write(f"player score is {str(score['Player'])}\n")
    File.write(f"computer score is {str(score['computer'])}")
```

Note: *f-string expression part cannot include a backslash*